# How to close a file descriptor in child process inherited across a fork, - does that the parent process remains open or not?

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, computer-science, file-descriptor

Within a parent process when a child
closes a file descriptor inherited across a `fork`. In other words, does the file remain open in the
parent, or is it closed there as well?

Comment: It stays open in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Every process has its own set of file descriptors. If you close one in one process, it is not closed in another process.

These file descriptors may point to the same file *description*. If you fork a process, then read from the FD in one process, then read from the FD in the other process, it will count as two different reads - not the same read twice. The first read will get the first piece of data and the second read will get the second piece of data. This is also how FDs created with `dup` or `dup2` work.

File descriptors which point to the same file description don't have to have the same number.